# How to give own dataset for keras-ocr custom training?

Tags: image-processing, keras, computer-vision, ocr, text-extraction

I am using the Keras-ocr for extracting weight from the digital weighing scale as well as from the cylinder but using pre-trained weights, I am not able to extract weight from the weighing scale and cylinder properly.

[output of pre-trained weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arq2N.jpg)

link - https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/end_to_end_training.html#generating-synthetic-data

So, I am trying to do end-to-end training for my own dataset using Keras-ocr. But I am not able to understand what is the data preparation steps. what is synthetic data?
Do I need to label the dataset if yes then how to label it?